# Could not build the application for the simulator: firebase plugin is installed but the crashes in IOS run with BUILD FAILED

Tags: ios, firebase, dart, flutter

Firebase plugin doesn't build on ios
I tried to build the app using Firebase core, Firebase Database, Firebase Auth, Cloud Firestore in flutter, So i got this errors
within : FirebaseAuthPlugin.m, FIRUser.h, Firebase.h
i have tried deleting podfile.lock, Runner.xcworkspace and then flutter clean nothing worked...

BUILD FAILED Error:

```
mds-MacBook-Pro:analise_test mdtaqi$ flutter run                                                                                                                              Xcode build done.                                            4.5s                                                                                                             Failed to build iOS app                                                                                             
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:69:53: error: incompatible block pointer types
    sending 'void (^)(FIRUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong,
    NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
        [[FIRAuth auth] signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuth.h:575:77: note: passing argument to parameter
    'completion' here
    - (void)signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
                                                                                ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:77:21: warning: 'signInWithCredential:completion:'
    is deprecated: Please use signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:completion: for Objective-C or signInAndRetrieveData(with:completion:) for Swift instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential
                        ^
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuth.h:464:73: note: 'signInWithCredential:completion:' has
    been explicitly marked deprecated here
                      completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                                            ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIK
    it.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Header
    s/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/He
    aders/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:64: note:
    expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:84:21: warning: 'signInWithCredential:completion:'
    is deprecated: Please use signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:completion: for Objective-C or signInAndRetrieveData(with:completion:) for Swift instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential
                        ^
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuth.h:464:73: note: 'signInWithCredential:completion:' has
    been explicitly marked deprecated here
                      completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                                            ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIK
    it.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Header
    s/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/He
    aders/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:64: note:
    expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:93:21: warning: 'signInWithCredential:completion:'
    is deprecated: Please use signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:completion: for Objective-C or signInAndRetrieveData(with:completion:) for Swift instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential
                        ^
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuth.h:464:73: note: 'signInWithCredential:completion:' has
    been explicitly marked deprecated here
                      completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                                            ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIK
    it.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Header
    s/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/He
    aders/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:64: note:
    expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:102:41: error: incompatible block pointer types
    sending 'void (^)(FIRUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong,
    NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
                                 completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuth.h:648:65: note: passing argument to parameter
    'completion' here
                     completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
                                                                    ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:130:37: error: incompatible block pointer types
    sending 'void (^)(FIRUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong,
    NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
                             completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuth.h:381:61: note: passing argument to parameter
    'completion' here
                 completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
                                                                ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:153:33: warning: 'linkWithCredential:completion:'
    is deprecated: Please use linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:completion: for Objective-C or linkAndRetrieveData(WithCredential:completion:) for Swift instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRAuth auth].currentUser linkWithCredential:credential
                                    ^
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRUser.h:334:71: note: 'linkWithCredential:completion:' has
    been explicitly marked deprecated here
                    completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                                          ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIK
    it.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Header
    s/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/He
    aders/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:64: note:
    expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:162:33: warning: 'linkWithCredential:completion:'
    is deprecated: Please use linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:completion: for Objective-C or linkAndRetrieveData(WithCredential:completion:) for Swift instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRAuth auth].currentUser linkWithCredential:credential
                                    ^
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRUser.h:334:71: note: 'linkWithCredential:completion:' has
    been explicitly marked deprecated here
                    completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                                          ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIK
    it.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Header
    s/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/He
    aders/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:64: note:
    expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:169:33: warning: 'linkWithCredential:completion:'
    is deprecated: Please use linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:completion: for Objective-C or linkAndRetrieveData(WithCredential:completion:) for Swift instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRAuth auth].currentUser linkWithCredential:credential
                                    ^
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRUser.h:334:71: note: 'linkWithCredential:completion:' has
    been explicitly marked deprecated here
                    completion:(nullable FIRAuthResultCallback)completion DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                                          ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIK
    it.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Header
    s/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/He
    aders/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:64: note:
    expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.9/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:187:43: error: incompatible block pointer types
    sending 'void (^)(FIRUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong,
    NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
                                   completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'FirebaseAuth' imported from /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:18:
    /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/analise project list/analise_test/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuth.h:607:67: note: passing argument to parameter
    'completion' here
                       completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
                                                                      ^
    6 warnings and 4 errors generated.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 6s.
```

Pubspec.yaml

```
name: analise_test
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  #  location_picker:
  font_awesome_flutter:
  timeago:
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
  firebase_auth: 0.5.9
  intl: 0.15.7
  cloud_firestore: 0.7.0
  firebase_database: 1.0.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/login-screen-background.png
    - assets/signup-screen-background.png
    - assets/starrbucks.png
    - assets/mcdonalds.png
```

POD file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'



def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf Pods/.symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p Pods/.symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter packages get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('Pods', '.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('Pods', '.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Flutter Doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/mdtaqi/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (6 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mdtaqi/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/mdtaqi/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2, Build version 10E125
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3.5)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 33.4.2
    • Dart plugin version 183.5912.23

[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.24.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 6s • 649A0E13-9AA1-4F2B-9458-99DD1FC2CD19 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```